# How to Process a Byte Array Image in Javascript Produced by ASP.NET Response.BinaryWrite

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image

I'm attempting to consume server-side code that is owned by another team and that I can't easily change.  It is processing an image and returning it via Response.BinaryWrite:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
var imageToReturn = ms.ToArray();

Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
Response.BinaryWrite(imageToReturn);
```

However, when I attempt to do standard client-side processing of the result, like using Javascript's btoa() to convert it from a byte array to an ArrayBuffer, I get messages like "'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range".

I really just want to be able to display and work with this image - so any approach that would get it to appear in a canvas, or convert it to a data URL, etc., would help me out.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the image, why don't you just `src` attribute of `img` tag to the url of the ASP.Net page, which is writing the JPG in the in the response.

If you want to display the image in canvas, you can do it in following way

```
myimage = new Image();
myimage.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canv');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(myimage, x, y);
}
myimage.src = '<url to the asp.net page>';
```